# get help icon name from FontAwesomeIcon

Tags: reactjs, fonts, icons, font-awesome

Please help me to find the import for

[image]
[image]

from

```
import { faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
```

I am trying to use it in html as shown below

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} />
```

please suggest the names for help and info like ***faTimes***

Comment: Is this a possible typo? "fortawesome" instead of "fontawesome"? Please include details about any error messages, and be more specific about what isn't working.

Comment: Sry typo is correct

Comment: I see, yeah, just checked the docs, that is the correct package. Have you checked the [gallery](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)?

Answer (score 0):

Try `import { faQuestionCircle, faInfoCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';`

I found it using the set [here](https://fortawesome.com/sets/font-awesome-5-solid)

Answer (score 0):

Look in the icon [gallery](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery) and search for the icons you want to use. For example, search for "question" and find "fa-question-circle" and convert the name from kabob-case to camelCase.

```
import {
  faTimes,
  faQuestionCircle,
  faInfoCircle
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

...

{[faTimes, faQuestionCircle, faInfoCircle].map((icon, i) => (
  <FontAwesomeIcon key={i} icon={icon} size="10x" />
))}
```

[image]

[image: Edit get-help-icon-name-from-fontawesomeicon]